# Spring boot - MongoRepository date conversion

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring boot with Mongo repository using Spring Data. My Spring application uses **UTC** timezone as default. When I query mongo DB by dates, I send the Date as follows in the `@Query: [...] 'TransactionDate': { $gte: ?4, $lt: ?5 } }` and send the Java date in the parameters. However, Mongo converts this UTC date to GMT although it is already GMT and when returning back data. It also converts to local timezone, as if it is not considering JVM timezone. How can I force mongo to stop doing theis conversion and understand that I already send the dates in GMT

Comment: No, you are NOT using the JPA API. That is Spring Data MongoDB. Totally different API.

Comment: It's not JPA or repository, you are trying the normal command instead. @query in jpa won't work with this type of command and for sure, ?4 and ?5 with be think as STRING (not DATE)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mongo compass uses local PC timezone to convert and display data. As for Java there is nothing to be done except sending the Java date in the needed timezone.

Comment: This query don't return anything because it's can't compare value in our collection with a STRING input

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.onlinetutorialspoint.SpringBoot_Custom_ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

It should solve your issue.

Comment: I am already using this. When mongo repository prints the query sent to mongo it uses this format: TransactionDate=Document{{$gte='Thu Nov 29 12:21:39 UTC 2018', $lt='Tue Dec 11 10:20:51 UTC 2018'}}} this date is GMT date, and my server is GMT but my PC is local timezone. So mongo at a certain level is converting Thu Nov 29 12:21:39 UTC 2018 to GMT timezone although it is already GMT... Mongo is considering that i am sending my dates in local format. How can i inform mongo that i am already using GMT

Comment: $gte='Thu Nov 29 12:21:39 UTC 2018' If this is **GMT** date then why it is containing **UTC**  code.

Comment: even this: TransactionDate=Document{{$gte=Thu Nov 29 12:21:39 GMT 2018, $lt=Tue Dec 11 12:47:10 GMT 2018}}}} is not working. Can you advise? It is like Mongo consider the server PC local date and not the date sent to it. Is it possible for example to send the server timezone in the mongo URL configuration in spring boot?

Comment: I tried 'TransactionDate': { $gte: new Date(?4) [...] } but its throwing:   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException

Comment: I have gone through the mongodb doc and it says that the UTC time zone is default timezone of mongo server, whatever timezone date it gets from the client it converts it into UTC and then stores it on sever

for ref - [click here..](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/) 
you will have to handle it from your java code.

Comment: also look this [Click here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310)

Comment: But i am sending UTC time $gte=Thu Nov 29 12:21:39 UTC 2018, $lt=Wed Dec 12 07:46:30 UTC 2018 so it shouldnt be converting, maybe it is an issue in mongo logic? Also note that the iso query on compass:  { $gte: ISODate('2018-11-29T12:21:39'), $lt: ISODate('2018-12-11T00:22:42')} works fine but from Java spring boot it is not possible -as much as i researched - to use the mongo isodate function. Also note that this format:  { $gte: ISODate('2018-11-29T12:21:39.000Z'), $lt: ISODate('2018-12-11T00:22:42.130Z')}  doe snot work fine on compass